# $\models P \wedge Q \iff \neg ( \neg P \vee \neg Q )$ is a valid argument

Tags: logic, notation

I have to show that $\models (P \wedge Q) \iff \neg ( \neg P \vee \neg Q )$ is a valid argument.

However, I have no idea how to interpret a $\models$ symbol WITHOUT a LHS. I have always seen it like this $P, P \implies Q \models Q$, which I read as: given the premises on the LHS hold, then RHS is logically entailed. Which I would then just rephrase as a formula like $P \wedge (P \implies Q) \implies Q$, and then use a truth table to show it is true for all $P,Q$.

Now, my intuition is, since there is nothing in the LHS, then RHS is just entailed for everything. And so the formula will be $⊤ \implies [ \ (P \wedge Q) \iff \neg ( \neg P \vee \neg Q ) \ ]$ which, simplifies back to $(P \wedge Q) \iff \neg ( \neg P \vee \neg Q )$ (using disjunction elimination and so on) and now I can make a truth table for this.

Is my approach correct? Or did I get completely lost.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  With nothing on the LHS, the claim is that the statement on the RHS is true in *every* case (which is correct).  And this is equivalent to having the single statement $\top$ on the LHS (much as, with $P$ and $P\mathbin\rightarrow Q$ on the LHS, this is equivalent to having the single statement $P\wedge(P\mathbin\rightarrow Q)$ on the LHS).  And yes, you can verify this with a truth table.

Comment: See [Tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)).